# How to achieve ajax pagination in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I achieve ajax pagination in codeigniter so that numbers should not be displayed in url bar

Comment: I haven't tried but m looking for readymade code so that I an implement in my application quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same using jquery. Below is the sample code I have Implemented on git

```
https://github.com/k10gaurav/codeigniter-ajax-pagination
```